# "Скорее всего(,) виноват он". Нужна ли запятая после "скорее всего"?

Tags: пунктуация

И является ли "скорее всего" вводным словом?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

«Скорее всего» в значении «очень вероятно, вероятнее всего» — выделяется запятыми.(Скорее всего, я приеду через неделю).
В значении «быстрее всего» — НЕТ (Этим путем скорее всего можно было прийти к дому.).

Answer (score 3):

Это вводное слово (в данном случае), поэтому да.

Answer (score 2):

Важен контекст: если оборот в функции вводного слова, то выделяется.